# how to trigger ‘animationEnd’ callback after all animation

Tags: javascript, css, animation, sass, css-animations

I encountered such a problem，i need to play animation by css3,here is my sass code:

```
.new-page4-play{
  .contain_doll{
    @-webkit-keyframes contain_doll_play{xxxx}
    -webkit-animation:contain_doll_play 1s;
  }
  .contain_photo{
      @-webkit-keyframes contain_photo_play{xxxx}
      -webkit-animation:contain_doll_play 2s linear 2s;
    .icon{
      @-webkit-keyframes contain_icon_play{xxxx}
      -webkit-animation:contain_doll_play 3s linear 3s;
    }
  }
}
```

and i want to trigger the callback after all animation complete (it should be 6s),but

```
document.querySelector('.new-page4-play').addEventListener("webkitAnimationEnd",callback)
```

will trigger callback 3 times,1s,4s and 6s,so what should i do to make the callback work once on when 6s?

Answer (score 0):

add a counter variable the can be accessed by the callback function

```
a=0;
someName(){
  a++;
  if(a==3){
     //do something
  } 
}
```

Comment: ...so,i need know the animation count of all '.new-page{n}-play' ?when i have new-page1-play,new-page2-play,new-page3-play,new-page4-play.......i think it maybe not a good way